# How can I add a line to a file in a shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I want to add a row of headers to an existing CSV file, editing in place. How can I do this?

```
echo 'one, two, three' > testfile.csv
```

and I want to end up with

```
column1, column2, column3
one,     two,     three
```

Changing the initial CSV output is out of my hands.

Any standard command will do. The important thing is the file is edited in place, and the line is inserted at the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This adds custom text at the beginning of your file:

```
echo 'your_custom_escaped_content' > temp_file.csv
cat testfile.csv >> temp_file.csv
mv temp_file.csv testfile.csv
```

Comment: this is more generic for all shell languages

Answer (score 76):

To answer your original question, here's how you do it with sed:

```
sed -i '1icolumn1, column2, column3' testfile.csv
```

The "1i" command tells sed to go to line 1 and insert the text there.

The -i option causes the file to be edited "in place" and can also take an optional argument to create a backup file, for example

```
sed -i~ '1icolumn1, column2, column3' testfile.csv
```

would keep the original file in "testfile.csv~".

Comment: Which version of Unix? This does not work on Mac OS X Leopard, which is certified 'Single UNIX Specification V3'.

Comment: I use Linux. Apparently BSD sed (including OS X) requires an argument for -i (and should probably be separate like normal arguments). Try replacing the command with "sed -i '~' ...". If that works, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Thank you. I suspected this, but then I fail to make the i command work. I tried inline command (without or with -e) and script command (with -f) but I get: sed: rename(): Not a directory. You don't need to edit the answer as long as it is helpful for the asker.

Comment: Great, but i think you should note the "1i" part, it's not obvious unless you know sed.

Comment: I think this should be the right answer to the question, cause you did not copy file or make a temporary file , this works will if you have a big file

Answer (score 21):

This doesn't use sed, but using >> will append to a file.  For example:

```
echo 'one, two, three' >> testfile.csv
```

**Edit**: To prepend to a file, try something like this:

```
echo "text"|cat - yourfile > /tmp/out && mv /tmp/out yourfile
```

I found this through a quick [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&hs=ySC&q=prepend+to+a+file+linux&btnG=Search).

Comment: Hi, this adds to the end of the file - I need it at the beginning - have clarified the question...

Comment: This solution is also useful when you have limited space and a big file, you can use it like this: `echo "text"|cat - sourcefile | gzip >tmpfile.gz; rm -f sourcefile; ungzip tmpfile.gz`

Answer (score 9):

As far as I understand, you want to prepend `column1, column2, column3` to your existing `one, two, three`.

I would use `ed` in place of `sed`, since `sed` write on the standard output and not in the file.

The command:

```
printf '0a\ncolumn1, column2, column3\n.\nw\n' | ed testfile.csv
```

should do the work.

`perl -i` is worth taking a look as well.

Answer (score 3):

sed is line based, so I'm not sure why you want to do this with sed. The paradigm is more processing one line at a time( you could also programatically find the # of fields in the CSV and generate your header line with awk) Why not just

```
echo "c1, c2, ... " >> file
cat testfile.csv >> file
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Use perl -i, with a command that replaces the beginning of line 1 with what you want to insert (the .bk will have the effect that your original file is backed up):

```
perl -i.bk -pe 's/^/column1, column2, column3\n/ if($.==1)' testfile.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a given line at the beginning of a file in two commands:

```
cat <(echo "blablabla") input_file.txt > tmp_file.txt
mv tmp_file.txt input_file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

how to add line inside a file

```
sed -i -e "48r../../../../folder1/lines_to_add.txt" a.txt
```

> a.txt - the file you want to change 48r is line number of a.txt  some
> lines are inside lines_to_add.txt file

```
../../../../scripts3_2d/lines_to_add.txt
```

> -i update a.txt, try without -i before run the code, be careful with new lines,

```
"keep a newline at the end of lines_to_add.txt"
```