# How do I prepend a string to each file in directory that matches my pattern?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I'm trying to prepend  `require_once 'bootstrap.php';` string to each `schema.yml` file in specific dirrectory. I'm linux newbie. Could someone show me the `one-line-magic-command`?

Any help is very appreciated!

**EDIT**
I need to search for schema.yml recursively.

Comment: The accepted response in this thread should work nicely: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487894/how-can-i-add-a-line-to-a-file-in-a-shell-script

Comment: "..show me the command?" There is no one command. `mv` http://ss64.com/bash/mv.html `for loop` http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/ and some general bash scripting http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html if you have no time check this http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/150

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find somedir -name schema.yml | \
   xargs perl -i.orig -pe 'print "require_once \x27bootstrap.yml\x27\n" if $. == 1; close ARGV if eof'
```

Comment: find . -name schema.yml | xargs perl -i.orig -pe 'print "require_once \x27bootstrap.php\x27\n"; if $. == 1; close ARGV if eof' ---- this command throws error: syntax error at -e line 1, near "if $. "
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
xargs: perl: exited with status 255; aborting

Answer (score 6):

Using sed:

```
find somedir -name schema.yml | xargs sed -i "1i require_once 'bootstrap.php';"
```

Comment: I had to slightly modify this to make it work on my Mac.  I posted my final result as a [separate answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144703/how-do-i-prepend-a-string-to-each-file-in-dirrectory-that-matches-my-pattern/8107718#8107718), so I could add the necessary formatting to it.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to review your spelling of "bootrstap.yml"...

```
#!/bin/bash
TMPFILE=/tmp/reallyuniquetempnamewhateveryouchoose
for f in `find . -name schema.yml`
do
    echo "require_once 'bootrstap.yml';" > $TMPFILE
    cat $f >> $TMPFILE
    mv -v $TMPFILE $f
done
```

Edit: well the one-liner above is better, even if it's a bit harder to understand at first :)

Comment: Two outputs become one: `echo "foo" | cat - file > "$TMPFILE"`. Note the use of quotes: `mv "$TMPFILE" "$f"`. The `for ... $(find)` fails if directory names have spaces. Use `find ... | while read -r f`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a followup to @dogbane 's answer, which I liked, but needed some tweaking to work properly on my Mac.  (I tried to post this as a comment on his answer, but I don't think you can put all this formatting in a comment.)

I ended up with:

```
find somedir -name schema.yml | xargs sed -i '' "1i\\
require_once 'bootstrap.php';
"
```

Specifically, the changes were:

1. The `-i` option to `sed` (the extension to use for the backup file for in-place editing) requires an argument, but empty quotes are sufficient (which tells it not to create a backup file).
2. The `sed` command needed to have a `\` after the address (but escaped, because it's in double-quotes, so it ends up as a `\\`), then a newline, then the text to add, then another newline, then the close quote.

Comment: thank you for answering this old question. i think someone will find this very usefull.

Answer (score 0):

Create a quick python script:

prepend_my_text.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import os
from os.path import join

TEXT = """require_once 'bootstrap.php';\n"""

def main():
    for dirpath, _, files in os.walk("."):
        for f in files:
            if f == "schema.yml":
                with file(join(dirpath, f), 'r') as original: data = original.read()
                with file(join(dirpath, f), 'w') as modified: modified.write(TEXT + data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and run it in the directory you are searching:

`$ chmod +x prepend.py
$ ./prepend.py`

The nice thing is that you can use string literals (triple quotes in python) to avoid worrying about escaping characters