# Pass String as variable in ed text editor unix

Tags: unix, ed

I need to add a header to an existing file in unix as a part of my requirement.  For that I used ed text editor got from this discussion

[How can I add a line to a file in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487894/how-can-i-add-a-line-to-a-file-in-a-shell-script)

This is the code I used

```
printf '0a\n%s\n.\nw\n',$header, | ed "./runtime/"$outputFileName
```

I obtained the value of $header from another file which is

```
"header 1","header 2","header 3"
```

After executing the script, When I check the output file the very first line of the file, contain only this line

```
1","header
```

How to make the whole line to get added in the output file? please help.  Thanks in advance.

PS:I am using Sun Solaris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

be sure to use printf correctly. (1) quote header (2) separate arguments by spaces

```
echo '"header 1","header 2","header 3"' > test.txt
header="$(cat header.txt)"
printf '0a\n%s\n.\nw\n' "$header"
```

results in

```
0a
"header 1","header 2","header 3"
.
w
```

Comment: By changing from "printf '0a\n%s\n.\nw\n',$header," to "printf '0a\n%s\n.\nw\n' "$header"" code works correctly.  Thanks for your input :)