# Edit tomcat server.xml using shell

Tags: shell, tomcat, sed, server.xml

How can I edit edit the `server.xml` file of a Tomcat server using the shell?
I want to insert a new tag from a text file into `server.xml` under the `<GlobalNamingResources>` tag.
I found many posts about the `sed` command, it's useful to replace a value by an other one, but in my case I want to add a tag and not replace one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sed` can be used also to insert lines in a file. This command append the tag `foo` after the `GlobalNamingResources` closing tag:

```
sed -i~ '/<\/GlobalNamingResources/a <foo></foo>' server.xml
```

the options `-i~` makes the edit in place creating the `server.xml~` backup file.

Comment: Thats what I'm looking for, Thanks so much, but can you tell me plz what should I change to make <foo> in the `<GlobalNamingResources>` and not after ?

Comment: @JoeKahla removing the `\/` characters only works if the `<GlobalNamingResources>` open tag stands on a line different from the corresponding closing tag. If they are on the same line you can't use `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for names of editor commands?

- pico
- nano
- vi
- emacs

or if you have the shell connected to a UI

- gedit
- kate

and I'm sure there are various others.

Comment: Thx for help, but I dont want to edit the file manually, I want to make a script that paste the content of my a.txt into the server.xml of tomcat under the `<GlobalNamingResources>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Just use 'sed' or '>>' unix command.

This was already treated here : [How can I add a line to a file in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487894/how-can-i-add-a-line-to-a-file-in-a-shell-script)